# Deploy solidity issue on Remix ide

Tags: solidity

i get trouble on Remix IDE try to deploy but no deploy button due to no contract can be select is first issues; second METAMASK no fake ether for making transaction need how to get some fake ether for dev. purpose!

[image]

Assume leocyber token.sol & IERC20.sol both of  no error...?!But IERC20 JUST COPY & PASTE. i'm not sure about that!
Thank a lot! i got fake ether ropsten test net. But i still have issue of no contract instances... it means nothing show it that can't select contract leocyberToken.sol  is that caused by socket not ready?!  Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrZrU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to test it out, switch the dropdown from `Injected Web3` to Javascript VM.

If you are actually trying to deploy, you will need some ether for the network you are trying to deploy to in your Metamask address, which you will either need to buy (in the case of the mainnet) or get from a faucet (such as this one for [ropsten](http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/)).

Comment: Before that i think about it using JavaScript VM,, but unfortunately i got issue of no contract can be select  OK! i will try it again later. Thank a lot! One more thing, VM no need fake ether for transaction?! if i need fake ether how to get some? Actually, i have idea talk about it late.

Comment: still can't solve the no contract can be select to compile ... please help!